# ConstrainValidator not recoginized

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I have created annotation

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyCustomValidationClass.class)
public @interface Feild{
    String message()

    default "{my.custom.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payLoad() default {};
}
```

This validation gives warning

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<MyCustomValidationClass> to Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>>[]
```

I searched various questions but I am not getting this, Please help me to reslove this

**Edit CustomValidationClass.java**

```
public class MyCustomValidationClass implements ConstraintValidator<CustomValidation, String> {

    @Autowired
    private RepositiryClass repositiryClass;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomValidation arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return repositiryClass.getDomainByName(value) != null ? true : false;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for your class - MyCustomValidationClass? Also FYI you've spelt "Field" incorrectly :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I added it

Comment: Are there any warnings or compile errors on MyCustomValidationClass? If you have a look at the ConstraintValidator javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html it needs to have an annotation as the first generic argument.  It seems the issue is your compiler doesn't think that MyCustomValidationClass is a valid ConstraintValidator instance.